# Where can I view the location history in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, privacy, history, geolocation

Windows 10 may track the geolocation:

[image]

Where can I view the location history in Windows 10?

Comment: Do your machine have GPS? Did you enable location?

Comment: @RomeoNinov no GPS, and I didn't enable location. https://i.stack.imgur.com/auj0l.jpg

Comment: So what is your question if you have no location data?

Comment: @harrymc  location data may come from wifi and bluetooth as well. While  I didn't enable location myself, I would like to check if the location history is empty or contains something. I am also curious to see how good the location is when I decide to enable it.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt when you disable Location in the settings menu like that, the location data cannot be accessed at all. Location data could be accessed through things like .net, but **only** if the service is enabled and desktop app access is allowed

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thanks, does this mean one has to enable location to be able to view the location history in Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you log in using a Microsoft account, then your location may get saved to the cloud though. `To view and clear the location activity associated with your Microsoft account, go to your privacy dashboard home page and look for Location activity under Manage your activity data.` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/location-activity-on-the-privacy-dashboard-cb8cde37-2569-1ca9-f011-2d07554912e8

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, if you enable location Windows will cache data only for 24 hours.